# Input Trouble With My Text Adventure Game

Tags: python, text, input, shutdown, adventure

*See my entire project code down below. It's not finished*

This is how the game works: You enter an action to do, and if it exists, the player does it. The code checks to see if a word you typed in matches anything it has resembling that word in that particular room. The problem is that the chance to put in an input isn't always given to you and the project just ends or command prompt closes. Please help me so that after every command you type, it's guaranteed to not just shut down like it is now and allows the player to input something.

```
import os

os.system("cls")

openleft = '0'
openright = '0'
room = '0'
lights = '0'
draweropen = '0'
key = '0'
unlocked = '0'
open = ("It is already open.")
closed = ("It is already closed.")
shut = ("It is closed shut.")

print(" ")
print("*Stuck? Need Some Help? Try Using Some Commands Like:") 
print("Open / Close / Unlock / Enter / Look / Check / ")
print(" ")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Welcome To A Text Adventure")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(" ")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("The Building")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print("You awake on the hard floor of a white room.")

if room == '0':
    print("There are two wooden doors.")
    i = input(">>>")
    if 'look' in i:
        print ("You see nothing.")
        i = input(">>>")
    if 'check' in i:
        print ("You see nothing.")
        i = input(">>>")
    if 'open' in i:
        if 'left' not in i:
            if 'right' not in i:
                print("Open what?")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'open' in i:
        if 'left' in i:
            if 'right' in i:
                print("Pick a single door.")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'open' in i:
        if 'left' in i:
            if 'right' not in i:
                if openleft == '0':
                    print("You open the left door.")
                    openleft = '1'
                    i = input(">>>")
                else:
                    print(open)
                    i = input(">>>")
    if 'open' in i:
        if 'right' in i:
            if 'left' not in i:
                if unlocked == '0':
                    print("You attempt to open the door, but it's locked.")
                    i = input(">>>")
                if unlocked == '1':
                    if openright == '0':
                        print("You open the right door.")
                        openright = '1'
                        i = input(">>>")
                    else:
                        print(open)
                        i = input(">>>")
    if 'unlock' in i:
        if 'right' in i:
            if 'left' in i:
                print("Pick a single door.")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'unlock' in i:
        if 'right' not in i:
            if 'left' not in i:
                print("Unlock what?")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'unlock' in i:
        if 'right' not in i:
            if 'left' in i:
                print("It does not have a lock.")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'unlock' in i:
        if 'right' in i:
            if 'left' not in i:
                if key == '0':
                    print("You cannot without a key.")
                    i = input(">>>")
                if key == '1':
                    if unlocked == '0':
                        print("You unlock the door.")
                        unlocked = '1'
                        i = input(">>>")
                    if unlocked == '1':
                        print("It is already unlocked.")
                        i = input(">>>")
    if 'close' in i:
        if 'left' not in i:
            if 'right' not in i:
                print("Open what?")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'close' in i:
        if 'left' in i:
            if 'right' in i:
                print("Pick a single door.")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'close' in i:
        if 'left' in i:
            if 'right' not in i:
                if openleft == '0':
                    print(closed)
                    i = input(">>>")
                else:
                    print("You close the left door.")
                    openleft = '0'
                    i = input(">>>")
    if 'close' in i:
        if 'right' in i:
            if 'left' not in i:
                if openright == '0':
                    print(closed)
                else:
                    print("You close the right door.")
                    openright = '0'
                    i = input(">>>")
    if 'enter' in i:
        if 'right' in i:
            if 'left' in i:
                print("You cannot enter both.")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'enter' in i:
        if 'right' not in i:
            if 'left' not in i:
                print("Enter what?")
                i = input(">>>")
    if 'enter' in i:
        if 'right' in i:
            if 'left' not in i:
                if openright == '0':
                    print(shut)
                    i = input(">>>")
                if openright == '1':
                    print("You enter.")
                    room = '2'
    if 'enter' in i:
        if 'right' not in i:
            if 'left' in i:
                if openleft == '0':
                    print(shut)
                    i = input(">>>")
                if openleft == '1':
                    print("You enter.")
                    print ("It is a dark room.")
                    room = '1'
    if 'enter' not in i:
        if 'open' not in i:
            if 'close' not in i:
                if 'left' not in i:
                    if 'right' not in i:
                        if 'open' not in i:
                            if 'close' not in i:
                                if 'unlock' not in i:
                                    if 'look' not in i:
                                        if 'check' not in i:
                                            print("What?")
                                            i = input(">>>")
if room == '1':
    print ("You barely see the light switch next to you.")
    i = input(">>>")
    if 'flip' in i:
        if 'switch' in i:
                if lights == '0':
                    print("You turn on the lights.")
                    lights = '1'
                else:
                    print("You turn off the lights.")
                    lights = '0'
    if 'turn' in i:
        if 'on' in i:
            if 'off' not in i:
                if lights == '0':
                    print("You turn on the lights.")
                    lights = '1'
                else:
                    print("The lights are already on.")
    if 'turn' in i:
        if 'off' in i:
            if 'on' not in i:
                if lights == '1':
                    print("You turn off the lights.")
                    lights = '0'
                else:
                    print("The light are already off")
    if 'look' in i:
        if 'drawer' not in i:
            if lights == '0':
                print("It is too dark to see.")
            if lights == '1':
                print("You see a drawer in the corner of the room.")
    if 'check' in i:
        if 'drawer' not in i:
            if lights == '0':
                print("It is too dark to see.")
            if lights == '1':
                print("You see a drawer in the corner of the room.")
```

Comment: Typically this is due to your program having errors. Try putting in a catch all and see if there are any errors, this may help you to fix them. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a while loop to continuously get input until the specified break condition occurs. What happens in your program at the moment is the code falls off the end of the if statements.

```
if room == '1':
    print ("You barely see the light switch next to you.")
    i = input(">>>")
    if 'flip' in i:
        if 'switch' in i:
                if lights == '0':
                    print("You turn on the lights.")
                    lights = '1'
                else:
                    print("You turn off the lights.")
                    lights = '0'
    if 'turn' in i:
        if 'on' in i:
            if 'off' not in i:
                if lights == '0':
                    print("You turn on the lights.")
                    lights = '1'
                else:
                    print("The lights are already on.")
    if 'turn' in i:
        if 'off' in i:
            if 'on' not in i:
                if lights == '1':
                    print("You turn off the lights.")
                    lights = '0'
                else:
                    print("The light are already off")
    if 'look' in i:
        if 'drawer' not in i:
            if lights == '0':
                print("It is too dark to see.")
            if lights == '1':
                print("You see a drawer in the corner of the room.")
    if 'check' in i:
        if 'drawer' not in i:
            if lights == '0':
                print("It is too dark to see.")
            if lights == '1':
                print("You see a drawer in the corner of the room.")
```

In this block of code, the input is only asked for once. if you do the following.

```
if room == '1':
    print ("You barely see the light switch next to you.")
    while(cond):
         rest of the code
```

then mark cond as false to end the loop when you are finished.

Comment: I removed all of the i = input(">>>")  But I'm still confused on how to loop in order to continuously get input. Sorry... I started with Python two days ago.

Comment: This is an introductory guide on how to go about infinite user input for games.

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ehmatthes/intro_programming/blob/master/notebooks/while_input.ipynb

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment to say thanks... but you're a life saver.